# Removing defined tests in Clojure REPL

Tags: testing, clojure, reload

In Clojure, I have decided to move from writing `:test` metadata elements to using `deftest`.  To see that I have written the `deftest` correctly, I try reloading and running the tests with a reload in the REPL.

While I don't care about [duplicate tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157411/how-do-i-get-rid-of-duplicate-clojure-test-is-unit-tests-on-the-repl) per se, when I remove a test from the source, I would like it removed when I reload the source.  [Clearing the REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636364/can-i-clean-the-repl) doesn't remove the tests.

So, How many I remove tests defined via `deftest` from the Clojure REPL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

clojure.test finds test vars by reflecting on namespaces, so you can use ns-unmap. For full details, see [my earlier answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570826/how-can-i-undefine-a-function-in-clojure/5571144#5571144)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remove vars one-by-one in clojure (I may be wrong; it seems like a strange oversight if that's true). The easiest way to get rid of old definitions is probably to use `remove-ns` to get rid of the namespace and then re-evaluate the file / namespace / definitions.